# Excel exporting a blank image in about 5% of my runthrough

Tags: excel, vba, office365

i run an output of football based datasheets for some buddies and I but not all are exporting correctly. I cant narrow down specifically why and if i re run the data a 2nd or 3rd time its often a different few thats an issue each time

Vb code below

```
Sub ImageExportNEW()

Dim filename1 As String
Dim Path As String
Dim Myrange As String
Dim dvCell As Range
Dim inputRange As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim i As Long

Set dvCell = Worksheets("Fixtures").Range("L1")
Set inputRange = Evaluate(dvCell.Validation.Formula1)
i = 1


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
For Each c In inputRange
dvCell = c.Value


Myrange = Worksheets("Macro Info").Range("B2").Value
    Dim rgExp As Range: Set rgExp = Worksheets("H2H 10").Range(Myrange)
    ''' Copy range as picture onto Clipboard
    rgExp.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ''' Create an empty chart with exact size of range copied
    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=rgExp.Left, Top:=rgExp.Top, _
    Width:=rgExp.Width, Height:=rgExp.Height)
    .Name = "TempChart"
    .Activate
    End With
    ''' Paste into chart area, export to file, delete chart.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ActiveChart.Paste
    Path = Worksheets("Macro Info").Range("B6").Value
    filename1 = Worksheets("H2H 10").Range("A11") & "-10" & ".jpeg"
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("TempChart").Chart.Export (Path & filename1)
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("TempChart").Delete

Next c
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox ("Saved")

End Sub
```

Comment: I had the same issue and solved it by adding `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))` before exporting the image. I know that some would downvote such an answer, but as long as noone comes up with a different solution, I get my work done with this little break.

Comment: a little break seems fine to me as i'd pop it on to run and leave it till finished. thanks will try it tonight

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this part of your code from ''' Create an empty chart ...

Why some many Application.ScreenUpdating = True !?

```
''' Create an empty chart with exact size of range copied
Dim xt As ChartObject
Set xt = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=rgExp.Left, Top:=rgExp.Top, Width:=rgExp.Width, Height:=rgExp.Height)
With xt
    .Name = "TempChart"
    .Activate

    ''' Paste into chart area, export to file, delete chart.
    ' Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    ' select chart area
    .Chart.Parent.Select
    
    ' paste chart
    .Chart.Paste
    
    ' export chart
    Path = Worksheets("Macro Info").Range("B6").Value
    filename1 = Worksheets("H2H 10").Range("A11") & "-10" & ".jpeg"
    .Chart.Export (Path & filename1)
    
    ' delete chart
    .Delete
End With

Next c
```